# Create Onboarding Tutorial for App using 6 images at the start of my app - stuck at actually creating the images

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, imageview

I have read a fair few tutorials on this and I suspect the answer is right in front of me, but I just cannot figure this out.

I have a tab bar controller and I want, the very first time only that my app is run, to have an on boarding tutorial of 6 images that gets displayed, where the user clicks the next button to go to the next stage.

I understand the NSUserDefaults part. What I don't understand is the step before it; actually displaying the image.

I just cannot seem to understand how I would go about displaying the images; do I create a View Controller in Storyboard and place that as the Root View with the arrow, assign an ImageView to it and populate an array of images? Or do I do this programatically? If so, how?

These sound like simple questions and I'm sure it is, but I cannot figure out how to create that view controller to display 6 images where each new image is called with the Next button being tapped.

Any assistance in the right direction would be great.

**Edit: Including some code**

In my Main View Controller..

```
- (void)displayTutorial
{
    EnvylopeTutorialViewController *tutorial = [[EnvylopeTutorialViewController alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:tutorial.view]; 
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"hasSeenTutorial"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"hasSeenTutorial"])
        [self displayTutorial];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

In the new tutorial view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.imageView.frame = self.view.frame;
    [self.view addSubview:self.imageView];
    UIButton *nextButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    nextButton.frame = CGRectMake(85.0f, 200.0f, 150.0f, 37.0f);
    [nextButton setTitle:@"Next"
              forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [nextButton addTarget:self
                 action:@selector(checkButtonClick:)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:nextButton];
}

- (void)checkButtonClick:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Tut 1.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Tut 2.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Tut 3.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Tut 4.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"Tut 5.png"], nil];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a third party component, such as [LAWalkthrough](https://github.com/larryaasen/LAWalkthrough) or any one of the other similar components you can find on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks - is there any convenient way to do this without a github component - I just want some images (already created) with a next button at the start of the app

Comment: Subclass UIViewController (no XIB). Add a UIImageView and a UIButton to its view in `viewDidLoad`. Add an action to the button in `viewDidLoad`. Define a NSArray property to hold the images.  In this action, change the UIImageView image property to the next one in the array. Display this view controller when your app loads.

Comment: Thanks my friend - this is perfect and exactly what I needed!

Comment: Hi @neilco - I have just updated my question with what I think is correct  of course my button isn't cycling through the Array yet.. please could I ask you see if the code so far looks ok, and if you can potentially update your code with how I would cycle through the Array of images? Thanks ever so much

Comment: @Lavanya Take a look at [this sample](https://github.com/neilco/Walkthrough) I've put together for you.

Comment: Thank you so much @neilco - that is absolutely amazing and it works like a beautiful charm! I will completely adhere to the license agreement in my app. I do have one question though - that works perfectly in the iOS simulator but generates an exception when run on my iPhone 5s with *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[3]' - am I missing something obvious? Thanks again though - massively appreciated and it works so incredibly well on the simulator

Comment: @Lavanya I've just run the app again on my 4S and I don't get an exception at any point. Have you modified it in some way?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42675/discussion-between-neilco-and-lavanya)